# Can't redirect to controller dashboard

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, redirect, codeigniter-3

This is the login script, when I log in I should be directed to controller dashboard. But the redirect doesn't work. I use codeigniter and the latest version of xampp.

```
function do_login()
    {
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $cek = $this->m_login->cek_user($username,md5($password)); 
        if(count($cek) == 1){ //cek data berdasarkan username & pass
            foreach ($cek as $cek) {
                $level = $cek['level']; 
                $nama = $cek['nama_mhs'];
                $nim = $cek['nim'];
                $id_user = $cek['id_user'];
            }

            $all_userdata = $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'isLogin'   => TRUE, 
                'uname'  => $username, 
                'nama'  => $nama,
                'nim'  => $nim, 
                'lvl'      => $level,
                'id_user'      => $id_user,
            ));

            $_SESSION['isLogin']   = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['uname']   = $username;
            $_SESSION['nama']   = $nama;
            $_SESSION['lvl']   = $level;
            $_SESSION['id_user'] = $id_user;
            $_SESSION['nim']   = $nim;

            print_r($this->session->all_userdata());           

            redirect('dashboard','refresh');
        }else{ //jika data tidak ada yng sama dengan database
            echo "<script>alert('Gagal Login!')</script>";
            redirect('login','refresh');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Remove the `print_r()` and the `echo` before the redirects. When redirecting a request, _always_ make sure there's no output before it. None what so ever. Not even a space or line break.

Comment: **Warning!** Don't use md5 for password hashing! [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) even states: _"Warning - It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm"_. You should use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a secure hash. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: thank you, but what should i echo?

Comment: Do you have some errors?

Comment: There are no errors, but the login function can't redirect to dashboard controller

Comment: You shouldn't echo _anything_. Like I said: _"always **make sure there's no output before it. None what so ever.** Not even a space or line break"_. if you echo something, it's an output. Redirects are sent as a header to the client. Headers are sent before the content. If you echo something (which is an _output_), the headers will be sent and then the output. That means you can't add more headers (like the location (redirect) header) after. And since you're telling the browser to redirect away, outputting content doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

aside from removing any and all output before redirecting like others suggested in the comments (as redirecting uses http headers), the `redirect` function should receive one of these two parameters:

1.- a full URL including protocol (i.e. `redirect('https://www.example.com/');`) when redirecting to an external resource OR

2.- a full controller/method pair when redirecting to an internal resource (i.e `redirect('controller/method');`

In your code you seem to be redirecting to the controller name only, which may on some cases work, but it's not guaranteed to. If the controller name is `dashboard` and the method name is `something` try changing your redirect to `redirect('dashboard/something');` (and do remove the `print_r` statement and all other output that could send out headers to the browser before the actual `redirect` line is reached)